# How to return a dictionary key, based on searching multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm fairly new to python and scripting in general so please bear with me...

I have a python dictionary that has key:value pairs where the value is a nested list containing positions for a 3d geometry matrix:

```
{Point_Index: [position_X, position_Y, position_Z]}
```

I should mention that the keys are unique, but the values are not.

How would I search the dictionary and return the Point_Index Key, based on the highest position_X, position_y and Position_Z in the dictionary?

Here is a sample of my dictionary:

```
Polygon1 = {0: [-3.1890000000000001, -3.1890000000000001, -0.30361509588790281], 9: [3.1890000000000001, -3.1890000000000001, -0.30361509588790281], 10: [-3.1890000000000001, 3.1890000000000001, -0.30361509588790281], 11: [3.1890000000000001, 3.1890000000000001, -0.30361509588790281]}
```

I'm trying to test the point positions to locate the outer most point in a given vector in cartesian space. So (max_X, Max_Y, Max_Z) could be seen as the uppermost right point, while (min_X, max_Y, max_Z) would be the uppermost left point. The lowermost left point would be (min_X, min_Y, min_Z) and lowermost right point would be (max_X, min_Y, min_Z).

I've tried various methods like get, max, but I'm really just stumbling in the dark from inexperience.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please post samples illustrating your question i.e. a dictionary with few points - and specify the desired output.

Comment: The easy way is to have one tmp variable, storing the key name with the highest X,Y,Z values, and a tmp list containing the current highest, and compare with the rest. You can do this with a simple loop. It will work. From there, we can talk about optimization.

Comment: what if two lists are like this `[12,10,20]` and `[4,20,15]`, what's the criteria for comparison?

Comment: what's the expected output for this `Polygon1`?

Comment: I'm trying to test the point positions to locate the outer most point in a given vector in cartesian space.  So (max_X, Max_Y, Max_Z) could be seen as the uppermost right point, while (min_X, max_Y, max_Z) would be the uppermost left point. The lowermost left point would be (min_X, min_Y, min_Z) and lowermost right point would be (max_X, min_Y, min_Z).

Comment: @user1510490: it sounds like you are looking for an axis-aligned bounding box - the maximum and minimum x, y, and z values?

Comment: Yes, that would do nicely.  I think I can expect all the data to be aligned in one of two axis' and I'm already testing to find that axis for another purpose already.

Answer (score 1):

```
max( (v[0],k) for k,v in dictionary.items() )[1]
max( (v[1],k) for k,v in dictionary.items() )[1]
max( (v[2],k) for k,v in dictionary.items() )[1]
```

Comment: @HughBothwell : I am sorry, I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max` with a `key` function:

```
>>> Polygon1 = {0: [-3.1890000000000001, -3.1890000000000001, -0.30361509588790281], 9: [3.1890000000000001, -3.1890000000000001, -0.30361509588790281], 10: [-3.1890000000000001, 3.1890000000000001, -0.30361509588790281], 11: [3.1890000000000001, 3.1890000000000001, -0.30361509588790281]}
>>> max(Polygon1, key=lambda k: Polygon1[k][0])
9
>>> max(Polygon1, key=lambda k: Polygon1[k][1])
10
>>> max(Polygon1, key=lambda k: Polygon1[k][2])
0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Python example should solve your problem.

```
score = lambda x,y,z: x+y+z

best_key = max(
    mydict.iteritems(),
    key = lambda i:score(*i[1])
)[0]
```

Comment: sum of `x,y,z` may not be the criteria to match two co-ordinates.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: yes; the point is that the criterion has been abstracted out of the iteration. If he wants to sort on a different criteria, he can easily.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work.  If I have a point with values (2,2,-2) and a point with values (-2,2,2) won't the score returned be the same for both?  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @user1510490: yes, the score is the same for both. If you can explain which one should score better, we can come up with a better score function.